# PHP truncate preg_replace URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, truncate

Need some suggestions for the methodology to achieve the following:
My current script gets text and if it has URL(s) then it replaces them. The issue is I want to truncate the URLS(s) so they do not break the width of a table or unsightly line break to fit them.

```
$text = file_get_contents("temp.txt");
$link = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
echo $link;
```

I am concerned that if I `substr()` the `$link` then it won't work if multiple URLs are found. Can you PHP the `$1` in the replacement? Any alternatives?

Comment: What is your truncating logic? Do you have a max-length in mind? What do you mean with "unsightly line break"?

Comment: I had experimented with substr($link, 0, 15); to give you an idea. The unsightly is meaning that the whole url line breaks to fit on a line in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback` to modify the match and replacement.  This returns the first 10 characters as an example:

```
$link = preg_replace_callback('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@',
             function($m) {
                 return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" target="_blank">'.substr($m[1], 0, 10).'</a>';
             },
             $text);
```

Comment: Barring further testing, this appears to have resolved the issue. I tip my hat to you sir. Its interesting that you ran a function as a solution bcz I had tried to run substr solo in it with no result. Smart...very smart. [Update] Tested multiple variations and it works. Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem can also be solved on client side using css (I assume you are speaking about the html element `table` in your question).

To do that, you have to give your cell a fixed size and to set the `display` property to `inline-block`. Then you can define the behaviour of the cell when a word is too long using the `white-space`, `overflow` and `text-overflow` properties.

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
.mytable td:nth-child(2) {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="mytable">
            <tr><td>abcd</td><td>www.smallurl.jp</td><td>efgh</td></tr>
            <tr><td>ijkl</td><td>www.a-giant.url/larger/than/the/cell/width</td><td>mnop</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried this on my first go and it gives 2 results depending on where I class the table - 1) it doesn't wrap and disappears 2) doesn't wrap and runs one full line breaking the table completely.